# Logstash unable to index into elasticsearch because it can't parse date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am getting a lot of the following errors when I am running logstash to index documents into Elasticsearch

```
[2019-11-02T18:48:13,812][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"my-index-2019-09-28", :_type=>"doc", :_routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x729fc561>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"my-index-2019-09-28", "_type"=>"doc", "_id"=>"BhlNLm4Ba4O_5bsE_PxF", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse field [timestamp] of type [date] in document with id 'BhlNLm4Ba4O_5bsE_PxF'", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Invalid format: \"2019-09-28 23:32:10.586\" is malformed at \" 23:32:10.586\""}}}}}
```

It clearly has a problem with the date being formed but I don't see what that problem could be.  Below are excerpts from my logstash config and the elasticsearch template.  I include these because I'm trying to use the `timestamp` field to articulate the index in my logstash config by copying `timestamp` into `@timestamp` then formatting that to a `YYY-MM-DD` format and use that stored metadata to articulate my index

Logstash config:

```
input {
      stdin { type => stdin }
}
filter {
  csv {
     separator => " "   # this is a tab (/t) not just whitespace
     columns => ["timestamp","field1", "field2", ...]
     convert => {
       "timestamp" => "date_time"
       ...
     }
  }
}

filter {
  date {
    match => ["timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss'.'SSS'"]
    target => "@timestamp"
  }
}

filter {
  date_formatter {
    source => "@timestamp"
    target => "[@metadata][date]"
    pattern => "YYYY-MM-dd"
  }
}


filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => [
      "@timestamp",
      ...
    ]
  }
}

output {
   amazon_es {
     hosts =>
         ["my-es-cluster.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
     index => "my-index-%{[@metadata][date]}"
     template => "my-config.json"
     template_name => "my-index-*"
     region => "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

Template:

```
{
    "template" : "my-index-*",
    "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {
        "dynamic" : "false",
        "properties" : {

          "timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date"
          }, ...
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "12",
        "number_of_replicas" : "0"
      }
    }
}
```

When I inspect the raw data it looks like what the error is showing me and that appears to be well formed so I'm not sure what my issue is

Here is an example row, it's been redacted but the problem field is untouched and is the first one

```
2019-09-28 07:29:46.454 NA  2019-09-28 07:29:00 someApp 62847957802 62847957802
```

Comment: Share a sample of your data so people can try to replicate your pipeline. Also, any particular reason to remove the `@timestamp` field? If you don't remove logstash can use its date to create the index name.

Comment: @leandrojmp added a redacted row to help reproduce the issue.  question about removing the `@timestamp` field, the main reason was just that I was already getting it from my file and didn't need to have two so just seemed logical to remove it

Comment: What is the purpose of the single quote at the end of the `'.'SSS'"`?

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer I found one post suggesting that that was how it was supposed to be but I can't remember where.  I've tried both with and without and still get the error unfortunately

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer found the post https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html . It's for non formatting syntax.  But I don't think that's the problem because I'm using that to create metadata which appears to be working.  It's the raw value itself that can't go into the `timestamp` field so the file can't be indexed

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the source problem was the `convert` block.  logstash is unable to understand the time format specified in the file.  To address this I changed the original `timestamp` field to `unformatted_timestamp` and apply the date formatter I was already using

```
filter {
  date {
    match => ["unformatted_timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss'.'SSS'"]
    target => "timestamp"
  }
}

filter {
  date_formatter {
    source => "timestamp"
    target => "[@metadata][date]"
    pattern => "YYYY-MM-dd"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing your lines using the `csv` filter and setting the separator to a space, but your date is also split by a space, this way your first field, named `timestamp` only gets the date `2019-09-28` and the time is on the field named `field1`.

You can solve your problem creating a new field named `date_and_time` with the contents of the fields with the date and the time, for example.

```
csv {
    separator => " "
    columns => ["date","time","field1","field2","field3","field4","field5","field6"]
}
mutate {
    add_field => { "date_and_time" => "%{date} %{time}" }
}
mutate {
    remove_field => ["date","time"]
}
```

This will create a field named `date_and_time` with the value `2019-09-28 07:29:46.454`, you can now use the `date` filter to parse this value into the `@timestamp` field, the default for logstash.

```
date {
    match => ["date_and_time", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
}
```

This will leave you with two fields with the same value, `date_and_time` and `@timestamp`, the `@timestamp` is the default for logstash so I would suggest keeping it and removing the `date_and_time` that was created before.

```
mutate {
    remove_field => ["date_and_time"]
}
```

Now you can create your date based index using the format `YYYY-MM-dd` and logstash will extract the date from the `@timestamp` field, just change your `index` line in your output for this one:

```
index => "my-index-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
```

Comment: I will definitely try this approach but am skeptical given the error `"Invalid format: \"2019-09-28 23:32:10.586\" is malformed at \" 23:32:10.586\""`.  It seems like it's actually getting the entire date and time but is just saying it's malformed

Comment: Also forgot to mention that my separator isn't just white space, it's a tab, and the file is showing that special character.  I have edited the post to make that more clear